# Ubuntu does not start a GUI

Tags: command-line, desktop-environments

So I was starting my VM, booted up Ubuntu, but the problem is, it didn't start the GUI. It just shows a command-line. Can you please tell me how to install LXDE or any other desktop environment?

Comment: please install ubuntu desktop version https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Hey just wanna let you know that I no longer play with Ubuntu. So saying goodbye to all you `dd` and `apt-get`. Now I use SliTaz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install a desktop environment by running the commands below (you will need to be connected to the internet for them to work):
`sudo apt install tasksel`
`sudo tasksel`

On the screen that appears, use the arrow keys and the space bar to select your desired desktop environment (PLEASE NOTE THAT SOME OPTIONS ARE NON-DESKTOP ENVIRONMENT PACKAGES), then press the tab key and the enter key to begin the installation of your desired desktop environment.